# Method signature not matching delegate?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public abstract class Effect<TAffectable, TOwner, TInvoker, TLog>
    where TAffectable : IAffectable
    where TOwner : IOwner
    where TInvoker : IInvoker
    where TLog : ILog, new()
{
    public delegate void AdditionalActions(
        TAffectable affectable,
        Effect<TAffectable, IOwner, IInvoker, ILog> effect
    );

    public AdditionalActions AdditionalPreActions { get; set; }
}
```

And this class is trying to set the `AdditionalPreActions` property of an `Effect`:

```
public abstract class Command<TEffect, TAffectable, TOwner, TInvoker, TLog>
    where TEffect : Effect<TAffectable, TOwner, TInvoker, TLog>
    where TAffectable : IAffectable
    where TOwner : IOwner
    where TInvoker : IInvoker
    where TLog : ILog, new()
{
    public List<TEffect> Effects { get; set; }

    protected virtual void CommandPreActions(TAffectable affectable, TEffect effect)
    { 
    }

    public virtual void Execute(TAffectable affectable)
    {
        Effects.ForEach(e => e.AdditionalPreActions = CommandPreActions);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

But I am getting a compile error with
`Effects.ForEach(e => e.AdditionalPreActions = CommandPreActions);`

Error says:

> No overload 'CommandPreActions' matches delegate 'Effect.AdditionalActions'

But it looks as though all my generic types are correctly defined.

Comment: Shouldn't `Effect<TAffectable, IOwner, IInvoker, ILog> effect` be `Effect<TAffectable, TOwner, TInvoker, TLog> effect`? I'm unsure if that would effect compilation though.

Comment: Are you sure the error is with `Effects.ForEach(e => e.AdditionalPreActions = Command.PreActions);` and not `Effects.ForEach(e => e.AdditionalPreActions = CommandPreActions);`  You might want to get things in sync when asking people to help you out.

Comment: @user2864740 When creating this code sample I used the wrong method name, I have fixed this.  `Post` was supposed to be `Pre`.  @Peter I have removed this character.  @Mick They are the same.  "No overload for 'CommandPreActions' matches delegate 'Effect<TAffectable,TOwner,TInvoker,TLog>.AdditionalActions'"

Comment: How exactly is your `Command` instance created? (i.e. with which actual type parameters?) Also, `affectable` of your `Execute` method is never used.

Comment: @knittl The command instance is not created in this library.  This is a supporting library that implements a somewhat custom but reusable version of the command pattern.  It would be the caller's responsibility to ensure their objects implement those interfaces and classes.  The `affectable` parameter is not used because it is intended to be used by the implementer of the Command object.  This class is not being instantiated yet, but I would expect this method to compile (but apparently the compiler thinks I am wrong).

Comment: Try changing your delegate to contain `Effect<TAffectable, TOwner, TInvoker, TLog> effect` as parameter. The problem might have something to do with co-/contravariance.

Comment: This worked.  If you would like to resubmit as an answer I will accept in the morning.  Is there a way to use the syntax in my original post?  It seems kind of annoying that you have to remember that it is the same type parameter as TEffect, and since TEffect cannot be labelled with in/out there's no answer that immediately comes to mind.